# problem on zlib

Tags: software-installation, libraries, header-file

I'm trying to install a package (named FIESTA). When I run make, I get a error message "zlib.h is required".
I'm pretty sure that zlib1g is installed, and zlib.h can be found in /usr/include. How could this happen?

Comment: What type / distribution of Unix or Linux are you using, and what is the process you are using to install the software, specifically?

Comment: @steeldriver The distribution is Ubuntu16.04, and it seems that this package uses gcc to compile.

Answer (score 3):

`zlib1g` isn’t sufficient, you also need to install the `zlib1g-dev` package to compile software using zlib.

Comment: Sorry, I meet another problem. It seems that the library libzlib.so still couldn't be found. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Congratulations, Stephen, you're now a personal tutor!

Comment: Nothing should be looking for `libzlib.so`, it's `libz.so`. Feel free to edit your question to add the actual error messages you're getting (copy and paste them).

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Thanks for your help.  This problem arose when I tried to follow someone's suggestion to run a process(which turns out to be incorrect and unnecessary). Anyway, the package was correctly installed after I installed zlib1g-dev. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer works for you, please accept it using the big check-mark.